# Stucked with a php function

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, function

Here is my code that finds Min size of subarray sum:

```
 function printArray($arr) {
            for ($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++) {
               echo ($arr[$i].' ');
            }
            echo ("\n");
        }       

       $arr = [2,3,1,2,4,3];
       $bestlength = count($arr)+1;
       $k = 7;

       for ($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++) {
           $marker = [0,0,0,0,0,0];
           $marker[$i]=1;

           $sum = $arr[$i];
           if ($sum >= $k) {
               $bestlength = 1;
               printArray($marker);
               echo("Len: $bestlength");
              exit(0);
           }
           for ($j=$i+1; $j<count($arr); $j++) {
              $sum += $arr[$j];
              $marker[$j]=1;
                if ($sum >= $k) {
                    $curlength = $j-$i+1;
                    if ($curlength < $bestlength) {
                        $bestlength = $curlength;
                        $bestmarker = $marker;
                    }
                }
           }
       }

       if ($bestlength == count($arr)+1) {
           echo "No solution";
       } else {
           printArray($bestmarker);
           echo("Len: $bestlength");
       }
```

I'm struggling with 2 things here I hope you can help me out

1. Where I have `$marker = [0,0,0,0,0,0];` I need piece of code or function but piece of code is preferred that can add 0 (zeros separated with ',' except the last one) and they must be the same amount as length of `$arr`.
2. I only can mark the corresponding items of the given array with "1" others they are marked with "0" but really I need to output marked ones with "1" items if you run the code you will see this output: "0 0 0 0 1 1 Len: 2" but I need it as: "4,3 Len: 2".

I hope you get the idea thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid I don't quite catch what the code does or what you want done. You need to work on your explaining (e.g. "this code prints the longest sequence of Mersenne primes found in a PHP array" or something to that effect).

This part I get:

> Where I have $marker = [0,0,0,0,0,0]; I need piece of code or function but piece of code is preferred that can add 0 (zeros separated with ',' except the last one) and they must be the same amount as length of $arr.

You want

```
$marker = array_fill(0, count($arr), 0);
```

but that's not `zeroes separated with ","` -- that is a *PHP array*.

Comment: Thank you so much I'm done with my first step(task) now only second one left! O btw I added at the top what it does.

Comment: What is the minimum of a subarray sum? You mean the minimum sum of 6, 5, 4... elements out of an array of 7, say?